# Increment the max of a column each time a value is found in power query

Tags: if-statement, powerbi, increment, powerquery, cumulative-sum

I have a column with values counting occurences.

I am trying to continue the series in Power Query.

I am thus trying to increment 1 to the max of the given column...but this is not working, I do not understand why.

I have a Max column which is the higest amount of ItalyZ at a previous date (I created it).

When I have "ItalyZ", I would like to be able to increment it, but it is sadly, not working.

```
  |------------------|---------------------|    
  |       Max        |      Geography      |
  |------------------|---------------------|
  |      0563        |        ItalyZ       |
  |------------------|---------------------|
  |     0            |     thrzjz          |
  |------------------|---------------------|
  |     0563         |        ItalyZ       |
  |------------------|---------------------|
```

Here is the costum column formula:

```
if [Max] <> 0 then AddedIndex{[Index]}[Max] + 1 else 0
```

I get the following error "The field "Max" of the reccord was not found. I have zeros for all my zeros in max, but when I have my Max in max if get this result. This is extremly frustrating.

I do not not know if there is a radically better way. Maybe doing this max value that I did previously is not even necessary.

As demanded, here are the previous lines of M code. I do not know how helpfull it is, because I have M code before as well. Besically I merged two files and I am trying to continue a series of number (increment) for each occurence in another column.

I will thus try to provide context.

**My strategy with M:**

I have one column with letters and numbers. My strategy was to split the column in between letters and numbers and then split it again for each four subcategories of numbers range.

My aim was finally to increment the number each time their category appeared in another column of my merged file (each tinme a country appears there are matching letters and each time subregions appear this is incremented within a range for each country/region). I am stuck sadly.

**My column description:**

The column that I am trying to continue has code which equals a country, AB (ITALY) or BE (UK) and then these letter codes have number range "subdivisions".

Following these letters, sepcific numeric ranges are associated. For both AB and BE, number ranges first from 0000 to 3000 and from 3000 to 6000.

I thus have the following possibilities: From AB0000 to AB3000 From AB3001 to AB6000 From BE0000 to BE3000 From BE3001 to AB6000

Each category match to the a specific item in my column geography, from the other workbook: From AB0000 to AB3000, it is ItalyZ From AB3001 to AB6000, it is ItalyB From BE0000 to BE3000, it is UKY From BE3001 to AB6000, it is UKM

```
#"Added Conditional Column3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value4", "Value AB Z", each if [Value AB Z and W] < "2999" then [Value AB Z and W] else 0),

    #"Added Conditional Column4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column3", "Value AB W", each if [Value AB Z and W] > "2999" then [Value AB Z and W] else 0),

   #"Added Conditional Column5" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column4", "Value BE M", each if [Value BE M and Y] < "2999" then [Value BE M and Y] else 0),

   #"Added Conditional Column6" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Conditional Column5", "Value BE Y", each if [Value BE M and Y] > "2999" then [Value BE M and Y] else 0),

    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Conditional Column6",{{"Value AB W", Int64.Type}}),

    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type2", "Max value AB W", each if [Value AB W] <> 0 then List.Max(#"Changed Type2"[Value AB W]) else 0),
```

Comment: Can you share more of the query code? Maybe just paste in the M code you see in the Advanced Editor.

Comment: Ok. I added the M code but also a description as well because the steps taken before are mostly preparation.

Comment: Maybe something like this 
   `Source = Table.Buffer(#table(type table[Values = Int64.Type],List.Zip({{5,5,5,-2,-1,5}}))),
    RunningSum = List.Skip(List.Accumulate(Source[Values],{0},(sum,value) => sum & {List.Min({12,List.Last(sum)+value})})),
    TableWithRunningSum = Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns(Source)&{RunningSum},Value.Type(Table.AddColumn(Source,"Running Sum", each 0, Int64.Type)))
in
    TableWithRunningSum` could work, but I am having difficulties applying it.